# Incorrect sub-array returned from Linq

Tags: c#, linq, jqgrid

Preparing data for jqGrid I get an unexpected array of cells for the subgrid. The simplified code looks like:

```
var result = new
{
    total = 1,
    page = 1,
    records = qstList.Count(),
    rows =  qstList.Select(( c, i ) => new
            {
                Id = c.QuestionId,
                Text = c.Text,
                Type = c.Type,
                Points = c.Points,
                Ordinal = c.Ordinal,
                subgrid = new
                {
                    subtotal = 1,
                    subpage = 1,
                    cell = qstList.Where(
                              q => q.QuestionId == c.QuestionId).Select(
                              q => q.Answers).Select((d, j) => new
                              {
                                  Id = d.Select(a => a.AnswerId),
                                  Text = d.Select(a => a.Text),
                                  Correctness = d.Select(a => a.Correctness),
                                  Ordinal = d.Select(a => a.Ordinal)
                              }).ToArray()
                }
            }).ToArray()
};
```

The rows are fine, but the array of cells for the subgrid are odd. I expected something like:

```
{[Id, Text, Correctness, Ordinal], ..., [Id, Text, Correctness, Ordinal]}
```

but it turns out to be:

```
{[Id, Id, ...], ..., [Ordinal, Ordinal, ...]}
```

How to get the expected "layout". Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can get the expected "layout" by adding .First(). So Id = d.Select(a => a.AnswerId).First(). Still the question why I need it for the cells and not for the rows.

Comment: For cells you have IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Answer>> - double sequence.

Comment: Try `...q => q.Answers).SelectMany((d, j) => d.Select(a => new { Id = a.AnswerId, Text = a.Text, ... })).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vladimir, thanks! Yes, the SelectMany will do:

```
subgrid = new
{
    subtotal = 1,
    subpage = 1,
    cell = qstList.Where(q => q.QuestionId == c.QuestionId).SelectMany(q => q.Answers).Select((d, j) => 
    new 
    {
        Id = d.AnswerId,
        Text = d.Text,
        Correctness = d.Correctness,
        Ordinal = d.Ordinal
     }).ToArray()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will lead you to the right answer:

- Create normal classes for all anonymous classes (Row, Subgrid, Cel etc.)
- Refactor all code so that there is only one Linq statement on a line

Now it is much easier to debug als you can see each subresult of all the Linq statements. I am quite confident that you will find the right answer this way. (If not, just add the single Linq statement that not work to your post).